# Get the width and height of an image in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have an image that is wrapped inside a couple of DIV elements

```
<div id="wrapper">
...
<img src="myphoto.png" height="400px" width="500px>
</div>
```

I use jQuery, to access the height or width I either use

```
jQuery(img).attr('height');
```

or

```
jQuery(img)[0].height;
```

Unluckily, when the wrapping DIV 'display' property change, these values are set to 0
for example, if I do

```
$('#wrapper').hide()
then
jQuery(img)[0].height = 0;
```

The same for the attributes.

Any idea how to fix this, showing the DIV, getting the values and hidding it again does solve the problem, however I can't guess the number of wrapping DIVs as it can (and their behaviors change).

Thanks

**Edit:** Thanks for all answers. However, I forget to mention that I don't control DIV hiding and style. My script plays with Images and is made to integrate in any page, so the user is the one who do hide/Show/change the values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to get the stored value instead, like this:

```
jQuery('img').css('height');
```

I know it sounds a bit strange, [but before you dismiss it, try it](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/FhfYQ/) :)

Comment: That will only work when you have explicitly set the width in either CSS or using properties. (indeed, the OP's image has these specified, I noticed to, just for other cases when the image does not)

Comment: @Pim: in those situations, you can get the computed style of an element using *window.getComputedStyle()* (W3C) or *element.currentStyle* (IE6-8).  If the element is hidden, you can show it, get the dimensions and hide it again before the display is updated.

Answer (score 0):

The same as my answer here:

[Convert css width string to regular number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530127/convert-css-width-string-to-regular-number/3530169#3530169)

Instead of hiding it with `.hide()` (`display: none`) you could hide it with `.css('visible', 'hidden')` then `.width()/.height()` will work.

If you don't want to change your `.hide()`´s then you could apply `visible: hidden` and thereafter `.show()` and then measure the height. After you have measured it, reverse that. Objects still affects the page layout when they are hidden by `visible: hidden` - beware of that.

To avoid tags which mess with the layout, you could set the position to absolute, move it to the body tag and then measure.

Comment: This has a different effect though, as the `<div>` would still occupy space in the page, often this isn't an option :)

Comment: Yup, I have added some more. This will also work without `height` set explicit.

Comment: It's actually a *good* practice to set the height :) This saves the browser time in figuring out the layout, and not re-flowing once the image is loaded :)

Comment: Agreed, in this case your solution is simply the way to go. But I also though about tags in general. +1 for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this, when you cache the width and height before the hiding you can still use them. Something like this:

```
var dimensions = {width: $(img).width(), height: $(img).height()};
$(img).hide();
```

Or when you can't do this because the hiding and the need for the value are spread out you could save the height and width in the data object

```
$(img).data('dimensions', {width: $(img).width(), height: $(img).height()});
```

Then you can acces them like this:

```
 $(img).data('dimensions').width;
```

You could even make sure that all images on the page have these data properties using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').each(function(){ //embedded images
        $this = $(this);
        $this.data('dimensions', {width: $this.width(), height: $this.height()});
    });
    $('img').live('load', function(){ //inserted images
        $this = $(this);
        $this.data('dimensions', {width: $this.width(), height: $this.height()});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$("#file").change(function(e) {
    var file, img;
    file = document.getElementById("file");
    if (file!=null) {
        img = new Image();
        img.src = file.value;
        img.onload = function() {
            alert(img.width + " " + img.height);
        };
        img.onerror = function() {
            alert( "not a valid file: " + file.type);
        };
    }

});
</script>
```