# convert length to unitless number

Tags: html, css

Without JavaScript, is it possible to get the number `16` (*a unitless [number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/number)*) from `16px` (*probably a [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) in pixels*)?

The background is, some css properties like `border-image-slice` doesn't take a `length` as value, instead it takes a number and use it in pixels.

For example,

```css
:root {
  --font-size-number: 16px;
}
.box {
  border-image-slice: /* this is where I need the convert */
}
```

I am aware that there is a JavaScript solution <sup>[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530127/convert-css-width-string-to-regular-number)</sup> and other than that we have some alternative solutions, e.g. declaring the number as a variable first so it's avaliable for the value of css properties like this.

```css
:root {
  --font-size-number: 16;
  --font-size: calc(var(--font-size-number) * 1px);
}

.box {
  border-image-slice: var(--font-size-number);
}
```

But still I am wondering whether there is any css function like `calc` or other magic trick that can do the convert.

Comment: I feel like the answer is no after reading https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#functional-notations but still looking for a second opinion