# Number() method doesn't give me proper output

Tags: javascript, function, methods

I'm creating a React project which includes images.
In my project I want to get the width and height of image that uploaded.
For that I am using

```
const image = document.getElementById("inputimage");
const width = Number (image.width);
const height = Number (image.height);
console.log( width, height );
```

Image tag in another page

```
<img id='inputimage' alt='image' src={imageUrl} width="500px" height="auto" />
```

Here `Number()` is used to convert the `image.width` and `image.height` into numbers for future calculations.
Whenever I run this code I didn't get the output.

```
const image = document.getElementById("inputimage");
const width = image.width;
const height = image.height;
console.log( width, height );
```

But when I remove the `Number()` then I got output.

Does anyone know why I didn't get output when `Number()` is used ?
There is anything I can do for converting the `image.width` and `image.height` into numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `parseInt(image.width)` (or `image.height`).

Comment: Thank You. It Works. Do You Know why `Number()` is not worked ?

Comment: See the duplicate (and [always pass a radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#parameters)). `Number()` tries to convert the entire string and returns `NaN` when it encounters a non-numeric character. Read the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530127/convert-css-width-string-to-regular-number)